# strange error message from website

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, websphere, load-balancing, firewall

I'm developing a web app using java/Spring. i handled the errors form my application and redirected to a error jsp. this application is now deployed in a client environment where, the app server is web-sphere, there is a firewall and a load balancer on the request path.

when i request for the URL the web page shows starnge message , which i know for sure that is not produced from my application..

what can be the cause for such kind of messages? load balancer? or the firewall?? any ideas??

[image]

Comment: Hard to say from this little information. I suggest you to check response headers (e.g. via Chrome's developer tools or FireBug). Some clue might be hidden in there.

Comment: Can you post any logs from websphere or your load balancer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this was from the loadbalancer, they have started blocking the URLs parameter wise, so when ever i make a ajax call to the back end, it blocks URLs according to the parameters loadbalancer is unfamiliar with.